# How to use perform method on SKAction in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, skaction, performselector

I try to call a function using perform(_:onTarget:) as part of a sequence of SKAction.

I've tried:

```
let action1 = SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: TimeInterval(0.2))
let action2 = SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.4))
let action3 = SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: TimeInterval(0.1))
let action4 = SKAction.perform(self.blinkLightByOrder, onTarget: UFOSprite._ufoBase)
let action5 = SKAction.sequence([action1, action2, action3, action4])

currentLight.run(action5)
```

When I use SKAction.run(block: () -> Void) like that:

```
let action4 = SKAction.run(self.blinkLightByOrder)
```

it works, but I need to send object as this method ask for SKSpriteNode:

```
func blinkLightByOrder(onSprite: SKSpriteNode)
```

but I keep getting error, and can't understand how to implement this perform action.
Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Comment: The error is: Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Selector'.

Comment: let action4 = SKAction.run(self.blinkLightByOrder) is working as run(block:) but I need to send object(SKSpriteNode) to this method.

Comment: Try `SKAction.run { self.blinkLightByOrder(onSprite: mySprite) }`

Comment: Thank you for this answer Orkhan Alikhanov, it worked great! can you write it as an answer so I can mark it? I believe it can help more developers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer posted in the comments by Orkhan Alikhanov

```
SKAction.run { self.blinkLightByOrder(onSprite: mySprite) }
```

worked great!

Now I changed the method like this:

```
       currentLight.run(
        SKAction.run {
            SKAction.sequence([
                SKAction.fadeIn(withDuration: TimeInterval(0.2)),
                SKAction.wait(forDuration: TimeInterval(0.4)),
                SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: TimeInterval(0.1)),
            SKAction.run{ self.blinkLightByOrder() }]
            )
    })
```

and it works just as expected!
Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your Problem right i think you're just trying to find a function like this:

```
blinkLightByOrder(onSprite: currentLight)

func blinkLightByOrder(onSprite: SKSpriteNode){
    onSprite.run(action4)
}
```

It worked for me and is just a simple call function